# Passing Auth0 User Id to service layer using middelware in an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to find a way to get a `UserId` string to my service layer without having to modify the request passed from the FE.

I am using Auth0 to authenticate users for an application. I use middleware to access the users id and set it to the `context.items` enumerable using this code:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var userIdClaim = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    if (userIdClaim is not null)
    {
        context.Items["UserId"] = userIdClaim.Value;
    }

    await next.Invoke();
});
```

And this works fine, so I get get the `UserId` in my controller using

```
(string)HttpContext.Items["UserId"];
```

Currently, I modified the request object received from the front end to include a nullable string `UserId` so I can pass it along with this code:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<AddressResponse.GetIndex> GetIndexAsync([FromQuery] AddressRequest.GetIndex request)
{
    request.UserId = (string)HttpContext.Items["UserId"];
    return await addressService.GetIndexAsync(request);
}

public class AddressRequest 
{
    public class GetIndex : AuthenticatedData {}
}

public class AuthenticatedData
{
    public string? UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Now for my detail and delete functions I only pass a primitive int to the route/body so I cannot modify it to include a `UserId`. Should I make every request an object with `UserId` even if it seems a bit overkill? Or is there another way to receive the `UserId` in the service layer?

I am using a shared interface between my Blazor app and the api, so I cannot just modify the interface to include a `UserId` (I think).

And is there a way to set the request `UserId` in the middleware itself and not with every controller function?

Comment: Why are you using middleware instead of accessing [`ControllerBase.User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.user?view=aspnetcore-7.0) inside middleware?

Comment: Mainly because I wanted to change the code in the middleware so the middleware does all the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would argue that in general case you should not add any properties on incoming model that you are not expecting to receive from the frontend otherwise your service can become a subject for kind of [over posting attacks](https://andrewlock.net/preventing-mass-assignment-or-over-posting-in-asp-net-core/) (for example for some reason in one service you forgot to set the `UserId` from the claims and malicious user provided one).

As for answering your question - one option is to try looking into [custom model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and implementing a special binder for the `UserId` property ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49910000/2501279)).

Personally I would go with wrapping `IHttpContextAccessor` into some service like `IUserIdProvider` and use it in services. Something along this lines:

```cs
interface IUserIdProvider
{
    string? GetUserId();
}

class UserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UserIdProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public string? GetUserId() => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
}

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserIdProvider, UserIdProvider>();
```

Though see the notes on [`IHttpContextAccessor` usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/use-http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#httpcontext-isnt-thread-safe). Alternatively you can create pair of interfaces `IUserIdSetter` and `IUserIdProvider` (implemented by the same scoped class) and set user id for provider in the middleware.

Comment: Alright! I will be testing the method with the `IHttpContextAccessor` since I can't really use modelbinding as my DTO's are in a shared project

Comment: You are a true live saver (and school project savior) haha! Thanks for the quick response and help